# How to calculate the Difference between SUM values

Tags: sql, teradata, difference

I am pulling total account balances for various dates and need to calculate the difference between those total account balances but need solution.

**SQL:**

```
SELECT SNAPSHOT_DATE,
SUM(ACCOUNT_BALANCE_AMOUNT) SAVINGS_BALANCES
FROM pIDWUserVW.PRODUCT_SAVINGS_VW
WHERE SNAPSHOT_DATE IN ('2015-01-02',  '2015-01-30', '2015-02-02', '2015-02-27', '2015-03-31')
GROUP BY SNAPSHOT_DATE
ORDER BY SNAPSHOT_DATE ASC;
```

**Results:**

```
SNAPSHOT_DATE   SAVINGS_BALANCES
1/2/2015    10,407,069,092.55
1/30/2015   10,581,034,604.38
2/2/2015    10,525,024,786.77
2/27/2015   11,105,597,533.96
3/31/2015   11,371,511,747.20
```

Here is what I want ("Difference" column) but I cannot find out the right function to do this:

```
SNAPSHOT_DATE   SAVINGS_BALANCES    DIFFERENCE
1/2/2015    10,407,069,092.55   
1/30/2015   10,581,034,604.38   173,965,511.83 
2/2/2015    10,525,024,786.77   (56,009,817.61)
2/27/2015   11,105,597,533.96   580,572,747.19 
3/31/2015   11,371,511,747.20   265,914,213.24
```

I am using Teradata SQL Assistant and get errors such as *Aggregates are allowed only with Window Functions* when I try functions like MDIFF but I could be doing it wrong.

Comment: Look for a way to do a self join on row numbers or whatever teradata allows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Windowed Aggregate Function are calculated **after** aggregation, you need a LEAD function which is not implemented in Teradata, but can easily emulated:

```
SELECT SNAPSHOT_DATE,
   SUM(ACCOUNT_BALANCE_AMOUNT) SAVINGS_BALANCES,
   SUM(ACCOUNT_BALANCE_AMOUNT)        -- current value
   - MIN(SUM(ACCOUNT_BALANCE_AMOUNT)) -- previous row's value
     OVER (ORDER BY SNAPSHOT_DATE
           ROWS BETWEEN 1 PRECEDING AND 1 PRECEDING) AS DIFFERENCE
FROM pIDWUserVW.PRODUCT_SAVINGS_VW
WHERE SNAPSHOT_DATE IN ('2015-01-02',  '2015-01-30', '2015-02-02', '2015-02-27', '2015-03-31')
GROUP BY SNAPSHOT_DATE
ORDER BY SNAPSHOT_DATE ASC;
```